# Another form of aficionado

Tags: loanwords

Does a form of the word aficionado exist where it refers to the person. Perhaps something like an aficionè ? Similar to how habituè is a habitual person or someone who does something habitually.

Thanks

Comment: But [*aficionado*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aficionado) ***does*** refer to the person: "a person who likes, knows about, and appreciates a usually fervently pursued interest or activity : DEVOTEE." Either you're confused, or you need to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective, like enthusiastic or fanatic?

Comment: Your _accent aigu_ is backwards. The correct spelling is _habitué_.